Can Fortran polymorphism work with allocatable arrays of different rank?
Can a Fortran subroutine use polymorphism to do something like this:
subroutine (inarr)

class(*) :: inarr

select type(inarr)

type is (real, allocatable(:))
   ! do something for 1-D array, maybe even allocate it
type is (real, allocatable(:,:))
   ! do something for 2-D array, maybe even allocate it
type is etc.

The syntax in the above is, of course, not going to work.  But I figure that what I am wanting to do is clear.  Any way to do it?

Do you know about assumed rank entities?

@francescalus  Yes, input was supposed to be inarr.  Fixed.  And no, "assumed rank entities" doesn't ring a bell.  Thanks.

There aren't too many (easily findable) questions here about assumed rank (have a look around to understand select rank(inarr), for example), but if you think that idea doesn't immediately solve your problem someone can surely suggest an alternative. Note, though, that assumed rank and polymorphism are independent of each other.

I do not understand the relevance of the polymorphism here.

Why don't you just overload on the rank of the array? Allocatable or not makes no difference then. Just as @VladimirFГероямслава unless possibly there are some non-array possibilities I really can not see what class( * ) is buying you (and even then I'm struggling but it is gone midnight)

Polymorphism in Fortran is about types of entities: how an object may have different (dynamic) type at different points of execution. Polymorphism isn't about attributes: if an entity at one point in time has the SAVE, VOLATILE, POINTER or, yes, DIMENSION attribute it has it at every other time.1
Within a procedure, some objects are allowed to assume part of their nature from another entity. For example2:
subroutine sub(a, b, c, d, e)
  type(*) a        ! Assumes the type
  character(*) b   ! Assumes the length
  dimension c(*)   ! Assumes the size
  dimension d(:)   ! Assumes the shape
end subroutine sub

Although each of these arguments may "look different" each time sub is referenced, only a is polymorphic.
In a SELECT TYPE construct only types, coupled with kind type parameters, can be used to discriminate cases. Attributes and length type parameters are not part of the selection process.
There's something like the SELECT TYPE construct which works with the rank (number of dimensions) of an object: the SELECT RANK construct. Much like how a type may be assumed, the rank of a dummy argument may also be assumed:
subroutine sub(x)
  dimension(..) x   ! Assumes the rank of the effective argument

  select rank (x)
  rank(0)       ! x is associated with a scalar
  rank(1)       ! x is associated with a rank-1 array which is not-assumed size
  rank(*)       ! x is associated with an assumed-size array
  rank default  ! x is associated with something else
end subroutine

This SELECT RANK ignores all other attributes, including whether x is allocatable.3
The associating entity in a SELECT RANK construct has the same interesting attributes as the selector itself. Notably, if the assumed rank entity is allocatable the associating entity is allocatable.
An assumed property can't be changed for that entity. An assumed type object, even though the thing is polymorphic, can't have its type changed until it assumed another type. An assumed type parameter won't change, an assumed shape or size won't change, and an assumed rank won't change.
Equally, there's not much one can do with something with assumed type or rank. (Assuming type and rank are motivated mainly by the goal of interoperating with a language like C which doesn't so strongly care about types and ranks.) You aren't doing much with an assumed-rank object except using SELECT RANK, associating it with another assumed-rank dummy argument, or using in a handful of other functions.
If you're dealing entirely with Fortran, you'll generally want to stick to generics: using type(*), dimension(..) :: arg may reduce the number of procedures you have to write, but it doesn't reduce duplication.

1 An entity may, for example, have the POINTER attribute, but be associated with something without the POINTER attribute. Still, the first entity has the POINTER attribute, and the second hasn't.
2 A character function result can even assume its length in a way best avoided.
3 Except for noting that an allocatable x will never be associated with an assumed-size array.

Maybe what you want is the assumed-rank feature:
subroutine (inarr)

real, allocatable :: inarr(..)   ! .. denote any possible rank

select rank(inarr)

   rank(1)
      ! do something for 1-D array, maybe even allocate it
      allocate( inarr(n) )
      ! ...
   rank(2)
      ! do something for 2-D array, maybe even allocate it
      allocate( inarr(n,m) )
      ! ...

end select



That has already been mentioned in the first comments. But it is really unclear what kind of problem that would solve or why the polymorphism (which you don't have but the title highlights it) is important. The code in the question has class(*), not real.

I know, but the code in the question doesn't attempt to take any advantage of polymorphism, so I am assuming that the OP doesn't actually need it.

I think it's perfectly reasonable to ignore "polymorphism" until there's clarification of the problem. We can easily view polymorphism as an expression of the known part of Fortran which seems "close enough" to what is needed that's it's part of an attempt to explain, not a part of the requirements.

@francescalus  I'm new to polymorphism, at least in fortran.  To my mind "polymorphism" means being able to represent one of several "kinds of things" with "one thing".  And to my mind, arrays of different ranks are different "kinds of things".  That's my inexperienced reasoning, anyway.  If I have used the term in a way that contradicts the accepted "dictionary" meaning, apologies.  I think it's pretty clear what I am trying to do, nevertheless.  Appreciate your pointing me to assumed rank.

@bob.sacamento Whichever way you call it, if you have to resort to guards like select type and select kind, you are not gaining much and you are likely doing it wrong. One usually tries to do heneric programming in a broad sense in a way where the compiler or the runtime selects the right code path automatically for you, be it using generic procedures or usong runtime polymorphism. For different kinds I suggest generic bindings when using type-bound procedures, or jist simply generic procedures in generic interfaces.
